# Trouble running Firebase database quickstart in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wonder if anyone of you have tried the database quickstart sample provided by Firebase.

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/database

I am able to run the Objective-C part but when I tried to target the Swift part, there is this error message: Firebase module is not available.

I am not too sure what I did wrong and if you have successfully targeted and ran the Swift part, may be you could give me some hints.

The pod file was included in the sample which is as shown below:

```
# DatabaseExample

use_frameworks!
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'FirebaseUI'

target 'DatabaseExample' do
end
target 'DatabaseExampleSwift' do
end
target 'DatabaseExampleTests' do
end
```

Comment: did you install the podfile?

Comment: yes, I did, using pod install.

Comment: try just pod 'Firebase' delete the other ones

Comment: Just tried removing others and use pod 'Firebase', getting the same error.  Would you be willing to help me to download it and try?  That would be helpful.  Thx,

Comment: Trying building and cleaning the project. I've run into a few issues like that and the build seems to fix it - especially if the project is stored on Dropbox.(your mileage may vary)

Comment: What do you mean by you are able to run the objective c part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pod declarations should be inside your target like so:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'

target 'DatabaseExample' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'FirebaseUI'
end
target 'DatabaseExampleSwift' do
end
target 'DatabaseExampleTests' do
end
```

Comment: @DarylWong good to hear that it fixed your problem. Would you mind marking the answer as correct in that case? Cheers, Chris